# AttributeError: 'TApplicationException' object has no attribute 'result'

Tags: python, rpc, circusd

I've got this issue while running `circus-serve` locally and calling the service with `circus-script`.

Tried different versions of circus and reinstalling dependant packages but nothing worked.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 766, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "./.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/envs/carta-web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 26, in _handle_and_close_when_done
    return handle(*args_tuple)
  File "./.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/envs/carta-web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/circus/thrift/servers/gevent.py", line 68, in handle
    self.processor.process(iprot, oprot)
  File "./.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/envs/carta-web/lib/python3.5/site-packages/circus/thrift/processor.py", line 100, in process
    result = tcall_meta.result
AttributeError: 'TApplicationException' object has no attribute 'result'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because I was using different configurations for the service and for the client.